# Should I delete the branch after a release?

Tags: git

I create a hot fix or release branch for a release. When the release is finished should I delete the branch?

If I delete the branch is there anyway to get information about it back again?

Answer (score 2):

Normally a release is marked with a [*tag*](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging).

So, if you are not planning working in your branch again you should delete it, since it won't be used and the release is marked with your tag anyway. You can create a branch from your tag later if you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best practice to delete branches when you're finished with them...

If you're using GitHub, you can track the history of branches using pull requests.  Or, you can always `git diff` the commit SHA of the merge versus the commit before that - that would show you the differences between before and after the hotfix.

Comment: But if I delete a branch are my not losing commits that were committed to that branch?

Comment: Sure you are, but why would you not merge that branch's hotfix into a master / stable branch?